# Multimap with unique values

Tags: java, hazelcast, multimap

I'm trying to store a list of objects in a Hazelcast MultiMap. Each object has a name and other attributes. That name should be unique for the given key in this Map. How can I configure MultiMap that it doesn't store twice or more the same name? I'm using Java as the programming language. We are using Hazelcast version 3.12.7.

Comment: If you insist that the name is a key  and that it be unique, why are you using a multimap? Have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say start here: https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/latest/data-structures/multimap.html

You will learn about all the options wrt to data-type available to store in MultiMap.